# For loop holding values

Tags: java, for-loop

This is a pretty basic `for` loop that I'm trying to design but for some reason, it just isn't working. I'm making a method that will have the user type in 3 test scores(integers). The problem, is that I need the 3 integer's values to be saved to a variable.

```
public static int testScore()

{    //starts method

int test1;
int test2;
int test3;
int i;

test1=0
for (i=1; i < 3; i++)
{    //starts for loop
System.out.print("\nPlease enter your test scores: ";
int test1=kb.nextInt();
}   //end for loop
```

Ignoring any syntax errors that I might have (rough draft), will this save the 3 values that I generate to test1,2, and 3, or just test 1 since I have int test1=... thanks.

Comment: Your best bet is take an integer array.

Comment: @user2888834, go through your code line by line and you sure will find out the mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is use **array**. But you still want to do without array :

```
System.out.print("\nPlease enter your test1 scores: ");
int test1=kb.nextInt();

System.out.print("\nPlease enter your test2 scores: ");
int test2=kb.nextInt();

System.out.print("\nPlease enter your test3 scores: ");
int test3=kb.nextInt();
```

But I strongly recommend to use array.
Go through on this link to learn array
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 3):

That's why there are [arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) in Java.

```
int[] test = new int[3];
System.out.print("\nPlease enter your test scores: ";
for (i=0; i < 3; i++) {    
    test[i] = kb.nextInt();
}
```

You're declaring `test1` twice - Once in the scope of `testScore` and once in the scope of the loop and that's not good.

Also please note that arrays are *zero-based* in Java, you might want to start the loop from **0**.
It's recommended to give the variables a meaningful names, not `test`.. consider to change it to `values` for example..

Comment: Don't forget to initialize the array (`int[] numbers = new int[3];`).

Comment: I believe both test1s are declared inside testScore; never as a class member

Comment: @RichardTingle Thanks, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand your question, you want to save 3 values (that you enter somewhere) in variables.
I think you should use an [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for that.

```
int[] tests = new int[3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {    
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter your test scores: ");
    tests[i] = kb.nextInt();
}
```

Later on you can use [Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (dynamic arrays), if you want to save an undefined number of values.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing the three values three times into the same variable so only the last entry will stay. If you need to store more values into a single variable use an array. Also you are declaring the variable new inside the loop so it will hide the external one...

```
int[] store = new int[3]
for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
{    //starts for loop
     System.out.print("\nPlease enter your test scores: ";
     store[i]=kb.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays instead of a single variable

```
Integer[] test_array = new Integer[3];
for (i=1; i < 3; i++) 
{    
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter your test scores: ";
    test_array[i] = kb.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop only gathers input for a single datum per iteration.

You have two options:

- Add special cases per variable per iteration  (This is a maintenance nightmare)
- As earlier poster replied use an `Array` of appropriate size and index it with same variable that is driving the for loop:

  `Array[i]=kb.nextInt()`